# How to force TeeChart gallery repaint?(swing)

Tags: java, swing, teechart

When I switch to/from 3D mode in graphics gallery, old version is still visible, it's removed only if I resize gallery(it's child of JDialog class)

Here is demo:

[image: demo of the bug]

Tried lots of methods - all these repaint, revalidate, refresh... etc, they don't work :(

**So how can I force it to redraw like when it's resized?**(I am rewriting code of teechart in my local version
)

Comment: Can you show your codes for the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` for the container containing the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another customer reported the same some time ago [here](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=953).
As you can see, I've just fixed it so the next maintenance release will included that.